# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\bigg[1^{1/\sin^2x}+2^{1/\sin^2x}+....+n^{1/\sin^2x}\bigg]^{\sin^2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Solve that $$\lim_{x\to0}\bigg[1^{1/\sin^2x}+2^{1/\sin^2x}+....+n^{1/\sin^2x}\bigg]^{\sin^2x}$$

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\bigg[1^{1/\sin^2x}+2^{1/\sin^2x}+....+n^{1/\sin^2x}\bigg]^{\sin^2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\bigg[1+2^{1/\sin^2x}+....+n^{1/\sin^2x}\bigg]^{\sin^2x}\\
[1^t+1^t+....+1^t]^{1/t}=n^{1/t}\leq[1^t+2^t+....+n^t]^{1/t}\leq [n.n^t]^{1/t}=n.n^{1/t}
$$

Can I use squeeze theorem here or is there a better way ?

**Note:** My reference gives the solution $n$

Comment: Why are you assuming that is is equal to $n$?

Comment: @user not assuming. it is the solution given in my reference for the limit.

Comment: Maybe I'm loosing something, I check it again. Thanks

Comment: What book are you reading? Would you mind giving the reference?

Comment: @Jack it is just with a bunch of questions and solutions, it could be wrong not sure.

Comment: Do you have any difficulties in using the squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$n=\bigg[n^{1/\sin^2x}\bigg]^{\sin^2x}\le\bigg[1^{1/\sin^2x}+2^{1/\sin^2x}+…+n^{1/\sin^2x}\bigg]^{\sin^2x}\le \bigg[n\cdot n^{1/\sin^2x}\bigg]^{\sin^2x}\to n$$

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. You have
$$n = (n^t)^{1/t} \le \left(1^t + 2^t + \cdots + n^t \right)^{1/t} \le \left(n \cdot n^t \right)^{1/t} = n \cdot n^{1/t}.$$
Now apply the squeeze theorem using the fact that $n^{1/t} \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: thank. but how do u comeup with left hand limit: $(n^t)^{1/t}=n$ ?

Comment: That is just a law of exponents.

Comment: i mean how is $n^t\leq 1^t+2^t+...+n^t$ ?

Comment: @ss1729 $1^t+2^t+\cdots+(n-1)^t\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be the function taken with the limit, then 
\begin{align*}
\log f(x)&=(\sin^{2}x)\log(1^{1/\sin^{2}x}+\cdots+n^{1/\sin^{2}x})\\
&=(\sin^{2}x)\log n^{1/\sin^{2}x}\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{1/\sin^{2}x}+\cdots+\left(\dfrac{n}{n}\right)^{1/\sin^{2}x}\right)\\
&=(\sin^{2}x)\log n^{1/\sin^{2}x}+(\sin^{2}x)\log\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{1/\sin^{2}x}+\cdots+\left(\dfrac{n}{n}\right)^{1/\sin^{2}x}\right)\\
&\leq\log n+(\sin^{2}x)\log(1^{1/\sin^{2}x}+\cdots+1^{1/\sin^{2}x})\\
&=\log n+(\sin^{2}x)\log n.
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\log f(x)&\geq\log n+(\sin^{2}x)\log\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{1/\sin^{2}x}+\cdots+\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{1/\sin^{2}x}\right)\\
&\geq\log n+(\sin^{2}x)\log\dfrac{1}{n^{(1/\sin^{2}x)-1}}.
\end{align*}
But we know that 
\begin{align*}
(\sin^{2}x)\log\dfrac{1}{n^{(1/\sin^{2}x)-1}}\leq(\sin^{2}x)\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^{(1/\sin^{2}x)-1}}\rightarrow 0\cdot 0=0
\end{align*}
as $x\rightarrow 0$.

So by Squeeze Theorem $\log f(x)\rightarrow\log n$ and hence $f(x)\rightarrow n$.